# How to declare wrap content to a dynamic button in code

Tags: android

Here is my code

```
Button myButton = new Button(this);
myButton.setText("Press Me");
myButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);


LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
layout.addView(myButton);
```

How do I add `wrapcontent` to this button?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use this line (I used FILL_PARENT to demonstrate)

```
layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: thanks myButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));     worked for me

Comment: hehe yeah you need it for my button! I thought for layout :) same thing

Answer (score 2):

set the wrap content for button

```
myButtonsetLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

or for layout

```
layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin**

```
val button = Button(context)
button.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
```